# Microphone in my headphones doesn't work in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microphone

I just bought a Skullcandy headphones with Mic but my laptop (HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC) doesn't seem to recognize the microphone in it. I checked the mic with my phone and it working fine so there is no problem with the mic. I can't find an answer to this query anywhere on the web. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My headphones have only one connection for both mic and audio. So does my laptop. Its not the same query @CharlieRB

Comment: Fair enough. I have retracted my close vote. You need to provide a lot more info though. Have you contacted HP support to see what headphones are compatible? Are all OS and drivers up to date? How about the BIOS? The exact model number would help too.

Comment: Have a look at your sound settings by typing sound into the start menu. Otherwise you may need to install additional audio drivers.